# Computer freezes and CPU LED hangs

Tags: display, cpu, freeze, led

My CPU led hangs(stop blinking and constant led ) and also hangs display.
It shows display problem sometime monitor shows out of range signal .
I have format windows(windows 7(32 bit)) number of times,but still it shows same error,I have replaced OLD RAM with new one please help me out

Comment: You need a lot more information here. I'm not sure what you mean by 'CPU LED'. Perhaps the harddrive activity indicator? If so, it sounds like your harddisk has a loose connection or is going bad.

Comment: Note that the LED usually indicates hard disk activity, not CPU activity, and disk IO shoudl not lock your system as you describe, so the problem (whatever it is) is likely causing two unrelated symptoms, the IO activity, and the display issue. This issue can be caused by a failing disk, motherboard, or RAM. Check the disks SMART stats to determine whether it is healthy. Memtestx86+ is a good open-source, bootable RAM tester. if you have eliminated Disk and RAM as factors, then the issue is either the mainboard or the CPU. I can't say I've ever blown a CPU, but you often want to replace both.

Comment: @FrankThomas An application will freeze the moment it tries to read or write to a disk that is timing out in Windows. I have seen this exact behavior a number of times on my failing drives :( When the C: drive is failing, everything goes to hell because explorer and such start locking up too. That would be my first thing to investigate.

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.